# Java - Getting XML content from JAXBElement using JAXB API

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxbelement

I have the following code which save hospitals data into XML file using JAXB API, it works fine but i want to get the XML content into a `String` object from `element` (the `JAXBElement`'s instance ) before saving it without reading the file again, How can i do that in few lines of code ?

```java
    Wrapper<Hopital> hopitaux = new Wrapper<Hopital>();
            hopitaux.setElements(getListe());
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(hfile));

            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Wrapper.class, Hopital.class, Service.class, Medecin.class);
            JAXBElement<Wrapper> element = new JAXBElement<Wrapper>(new QName("hopitaux"), Wrapper.class, hopitaux);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "iso-8859-15");
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            m.marshal(element, System.out);
            m.marshal(element, writer);
            writer.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marshal it to a `StringWriter` to capture the output in a string. You will have to move the encoding from the `Marshaller` to the point where you write out the string to the file, though, I think.

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
m.marshal(element, stringWriter);
String content = stringWriter.toString();
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(hfile, 
        Charset.forName("ISO-8859-15"))) {
    writer.write(content);
}
```

(Assuming `hfile` is a `Path`, otherwise use `Paths.get(hfile)` or `hfile.toPath()` as appropriate.)